# Express-generator is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

I suspect i could have changed where node modules are installed.I have installed express-generator globally.

> D:\chirp> npm install express-generator -g

When i try running

> D:\chirp> express --ejs

An error popsup in the Command prompt saying

> 'express' is not recognised as an internal or external
>   command,operable program or batch file
>   [Here is a screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQpdx.png)

Comment: do: `npm install express-generator -g`, and dont forget about whitespace before --ejs, example: `express --ejs projname`

Comment: @dev-l i have done that and it still doesnt work i have added an image attachment to my question kindly have a look at it and see if you could know what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run

```
npm bin -g
```

To see where npm installs it's global binaries. Then add that directory to your PATH.

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;[new directory]
```

And add it permanently using the way that you should on your system.

Answer (score 2):

simply use

```
npx express-generator [your projectName]
```

Comment: I prefer using npx as well, it's recommended by npm, while `npm i -g` is recommended against by them as well.